# What advances have been made in liver transplants in the past 30 years?

Tags: liver, organ-transplant, transplant-rejection

Imagine someone needing a liver transplant 30 years ago versus today. What advances have been made to make the procedure safer now?

## My research

---

I know that the constant in all organ transplants has been the need to take immunosuppressants. This hasn't changed in the past 30 years.

I see here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2886399/ that common complications today are renal failure and the impact of immunosuppressants on renal function. I don't quite understand how the liver transplant ends up affecting the kidneys, but hope the risk is largely managed in the future.

It also touches on better matching of donors with patients.

From: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/eji.202048875

"The intricate management of immunosuppressive regimens, balancing desired immunological quiescence while minimizing toxicity has proven challenging. Diminishing improvements in long-term morbidity and mortality have been inextricably linked with the protracted use of these medications."

This suggests that the immunosuppressive medication required post transplant does have negative impacts on longevity. I'm hoping we might be able to address this in the future.

---

Note: I really wanted to ask what advancements are likely to happen in the next 30 years, but that would make the question speculative.

Comment: If I may point you in an interesting direction, you may find that changes in the approach to transplants are occurring at a fundamental level: [engineered liver tissue](https://news.mit.edu/2017/engineered-liver-tissue-expands-after-transplant-0719) may lead you to further questions about the future of medicine.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks for sharing. This is very encouraging indeed.